# Any opensource tool for analysing JMeter result file like JTL or CSV and produce good reports

Tags: csv, jmeter

We are using JMeter for Performance testing and mostly user range of 200 to 500 users. One issue which we face is quality of JMeter reports.

Is there any opensource tool preferably in JAVA, which will take CSV or JTL file as input and will produce good quality reports and graphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware of at least 3 solutions:

1. [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which are open-source. See [Automatically generating nice graphs at end of your Load Test with Apache JMeter and JMeter-Plugins](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/automatically-generating-nice-graphs-at-end-of-your-load-test-with-apache-jmeter-and-jmeter-plugins/) guide for details.
2. You can use [Loadosophia.org](http://loadosophia.org/) online service which provides online results analysis capabilities
3. You can use [Blazemeter plugin to JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/83191-blazemeter-plugin-to-jmeter) which is a cloud-based solution like point 2 but having different test runs results comparison feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of one more online tool
Janalyzer, we can create an account and will give our CSV or XML results file as input and it will give PDF format report

Comment: I tied it. I has limit on the report file: Max size of zip file should be less than 1 MB . It can't be serious